# How to set text in textarea using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried entering text in textarea using driver.findElement(By.classname("aoT")).sendKeys("hello") but it is throwing an exception Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string.

```
public class Test_sele {
static WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\ffdriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    WebElement compose = driver.findElement(By.className("z0"));
    compose.click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    //WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.className("aoT"));
    //System.out.println(to);
    //to.sendKeys("na");
    //to.click();
    //to.sendKeys("na");
    driver.findElement(By.className("aoT")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.className("aoT")).sendKeys("hello");
    driver.close();

}
```

}

Please help me out with other alternative or some modification
Thanks

Comment: why revert an edit that improves your post formatting? just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a problem of the Selenium and Firefox version you are using. Try downgrading Firefox and use the latest version of the gecko driver.

Try the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("to")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.name("to")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name("to")).sendKeys("test@g.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for your element")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for your element")).sendKeys("test");
```